# Reloading data from the database for dropdownlist without refreshing whole page

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, model-view-controller

I am looking for a solution to reload data from dropdownlist after pressing the button. The most important thing is that only the dropdownlist form should be reloaded.

// This is View in Controller

```
    public ActionResult DodajWydanie()
    {
        var Tworcy = _context.Tworcys.ToList();
        var Ksiazka = _context.Ksiazkas.ToList();
        var Wydawnictwo = _context.Wydawnictwos.ToList();

        var viewModelWydanie = new WydanieViewModel
        {
            Ksiazkas = Ksiazka,
            Tworcies = Tworcy,
            Wydawnictwos = Wydawnictwo,

        };
        return View("DodajWydanie", viewModelWydanie);
    }
```

// DropDownlist in View

```
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateWydanie", "Biblioteka", null,
             new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "OnSuccess", OnFailure = "OnFailure" },
               new { id = "WydanieFrom" }))
            {
                <div class="form-group" id="DdKsiazka">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Wydanie.Tworcy.KsiazkaId)
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Wydanie.TworcyId, new SelectList(Model.Tworcies, "Id", "Full"), "", new { @id = "DropKs", @class = "form-control" })
                    <input type="button" value="Dodaj Książkę" id="loadData2" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

// And script

```
    $('#asd').click(function () {
           var f = {};
           f.success = function () {
               $('#formid')[0].reset();
               // Here i need same code to reload @id = DropKs
           };
            $.ajax(f);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour of the button click will refresh the page, so if you want to prevent that then you will need to make use of [preventDefault();](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) like so...

```
    $('#loadData2').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // This will stop the page from refreshing.
        var f = {};
        f.success = function () {
        $('#formid')[0].reset();
               // Here i need same code to reload @id = DropKs
        };
        $.ajax(f);
    });
```

Comment: Ok, but i still need to realod DropDownListFor with new submited data.

Comment: How its look, I've got on partial View with DropDownListFor id=DropKs and button id = loadData2. When i clicked id = loadData2 he show me another partial view (on same page, without refresh). And on this secend partial View i've got Submit button (This button save data in database). Then when he save on database i need to reload data in id=DropKs. I want do this without refreshing all page.

Comment: @Crower I think the best approach for that would be to set up a [Web API](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/apis) endpoint for retrieving the data that you need. You could set up an endpoint which would receive some input parameters (the data submitted on the page), and return a list of JSON data that you could use for populating the dropdown list.